# Data model for nested array of objects in Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, data-modeling

I need advice from experienced NoSQL engineers on how I should structure my data.

- I want to model my SQL data structure to NoSQL for Google Cloud Firestore.
- I have no prior experience with NoSQL databases but I am proficient with traditional SQL.
- I use Node.js for writing queries.

So far, I converted three tables to JSON documents with example data:

```
{
  "session": {
      "userId": 99992222,
      "token": "jwttoken1191891j1kj1khjjk1hjk1kj1",
      "created": "timestamp"
  }
}
```

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 99992222,
    "username": "userName",
    "avatarUrl": "https://url-xxxx.com",
    "lastLogin": "2019-11-23 13:59:48.884549",
    "created": "2019-11-23 13:59:48.884549",
    "modified": "2019-11-23 13:59:48.884549",
    "visits": 1,
    "profile": true,
    "basketDetail": { // I get this data from a third party API
      "response": { 
        "product_count": 2,
        "products": [
          {
            "product_id": 111,
            "usageInMinutes_recent": 0,
            "usageInMinutes": 0,
            "usageInMinutes_windows": 0,
            "usageInMinutes_mac": 0,
            "usageInMinutes_linux": 0
          },
          {
            "product_id": 222,  // no recent usage here
            "usageInMinutes": 0,
            "usageInMinutes_windows": 0,
            "usageInMinutes_mac": 0,
            "usageInMinutes_linux": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "visitor": {
    "id": 999922221,
    "created": "2019-11-23 13:59:48.884549"
  }
}
```

My questions:

1. session.userId, user.id, visitor.id can all signify the same user. What is the Firestore equivalent to foreign keys in SQL? How would I connect/join these three collections in a query?
2. What do I do about the nested object `basketDetail`? Is it fine where it is or should I define its own collection? 
    I anticipate queries

   - occasionally add all the recent usage.
   - frequently check if a user owns a specific product_id
   - frequently replace the whole `baskedDetail` object with new data.
   - occasionally update one specific product_id.
3. How would I connect collections `user` with `basketDetail` in a query if I separated it?

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. session.userId, user.id, visitor.id can all signify the same user. What is the Firestore equivalent to foreign keys in SQL? How would I connect/join these three collections in a query?

Unfortunately, there is not `JOIN` clause in Firestore. Queries in Firestore are shallow, can only get elements from the collection that the query is run against. There is no way you can get documents from two collections in a single query unless you are using [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), but it's not the case since the collections in your project have different names.

If you have three collections, then three separate queries are required. There is no way you can achieve that in a single go.

> 2. What do I do about the nested object basketDetail? Is it fine where it is or should I define its own collection?

There are some limits when it comes to how much data you can put into a document. According to the official documentation regarding [usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas):

> Maximum size for a document: 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)

As you can see, you are limited to 1 MiB total of data in a single document. So if you think that nested object `basketDetail` can stay within this limitation then you can use that schema, otherwise, add it to a subcollection. Besides that, all those operations are permitted in Firestore. If you'll have hard times implementing them, post another question so we can take a look at it.

> How would I connect collections user with basketDetail in a query if I separated it?

You cannot connect/join two collections. If you separate `basketDetail` in a subcollection, then two queries are required.